# Python: file contents to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that accepts a filename(string) of a CSV file which
>   contains the information about student's names and their grades  for
>   four courses and returns a dictionary of the information. The keys of
>   the dictionary should be the name of the students and  the values
>   should be a list of floating point numbers of their grades. For
>   example, if the content of the file looks like this:

```
Mark,90,93,60,90
Abigail,84,50,72,75
Frank,46,83,53,79
Yohaan,47,77,74,96
```

> then your function should return a dictionary such as:

```
out_dict = {'Frank': [46.0, 83.0, 53.0, 79.0],
            'Mark': [90.0, 93.0, 60.0, 90.0],
            'Yohaan': [47.0, 77.0, 74.0, 96.0],
            'Abigail': [84.0, 50.0, 72.0, 75.0]}
```

This is my code:

```
def dict_from_file (file_name):
    file_pointer = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    print (data)
    output_dict = {}
    for line in data:

    file_pointer.close()
    return (output_dict)

#Main Program
file_name = input("Enter the exact file name with its extension (.i.e., .txt): ")
result = dict_from_file (file_name)
print (result)
```

As you can see the statements are missing inside the for loop. The problem is I cannot find any logic to first take the input from the file and paste it in a dictionary. And if I plan to extract each line once how will I add it to the dictionary with name as the key and the four numbers as the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To strictly focus on your code:

If you print out what you've read, you will notice you have this:

```
['Mark,90,93,60,90\n', 'Abigail,84,50,72,75\n', 'Frank,46,83,53,79\n', 'Yohaan,47,77,74,96']
```

So, when you are iterating through each item in your list, to keep this example simple, you can pretty much extract the first item, which will now be your key, and then take the part of the list that excludes the name and cast each item to a float.

So, you pretty much are looking for:

```
l = line.split(',')
output_dict[l[0]] = map(float, l[1:])
```

What is happening up there is that you are taking each item you are iterating over, making it a list, by splitting on ','. Then you are going to take the first item in the list and make that your key. Then to assign your value, you have to make use of the `map` method, which will map out each item in your `list` to a float.

You are going to do that operation for each `line` being read.

So, finally, you will have:

```
def dict_from_file (file_name):
    file_pointer = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    print (data)
    output_dict = {}
    for line in data:
        l = line.split(',')
        output_dict[l[0]] = map(float, l[1:])
    file_pointer.close()
    return output_dict

#Main Program
result = dict_from_file ('stuff.txt')
print (result)
```

Running that code, will give you:

```
{'Frank': [46.0, 83.0, 53.0, 79.0], 'Yohaan': [47.0, 77.0, 74.0, 96.0], 'Abigail': [84.0, 50.0, 72.0, 75.0], 'Mark': [90.0, 93.0, 60.0, 90.0]}
```

Comment: I suggest a combination of this answer (multiple columns) and srowland's, which uses a CSV reader. This solution will fail for a perfectly valid CSV line like: "Smith, John",10,10,10,10

Comment: @brianpck Fair enough. The solution was put together keeping in mind the data structure that was provided. OP can leverage what they wish from the solutions. :)

Comment: Actually I am just learning python so I need to acquaint myself with the built in functions and their use. Thanks a lot for the solution though.

Comment: @KaranThakkar Don't forget to accept the solution you found most helpful. It helps indicate to other users that the solution you chose to your question solved your problem.

Comment: @KaranThakkar No need to apologize. :) Just a friendly reminder. And thank you for accepting.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use csv reader:

```
import csv
with open(file_name, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csv_reader:
        output_dict[row[0]] = [float(n) for n in row[1:]]
```

Something like that should work if correctly inserted into your for loop. I haven't tested the code, but it shouldn't be too far off.

Comment: Yes, that _should_ work. But you might as well make it more general, so it can handle any number of scores, rather than hard-coding it for 4 values.

Comment: Fair point, thanks, could borrow the excellent map from @idjaw's answer and use something like output_dict[row[0]] = map(float, row[1:])

Comment: [Don't use `map`](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196), though!

Comment: Thanks brianpck - I had no idea it was frowned upon. I've always enjoyed a nice list comprehension, so will stick with those instead. In fact I'll edit one into my answer :). Just proves answering q's is as useful as asking them on SO!

Comment: Pfft. What would Guido know. :) Seriously though, I agreed with Guido's logic when he first wrote that article, and generally prefer a list comp or generator expression. But sometimes using `map` or `filter` is handy & concise. My rule of thumb is that if it requires a `lambda` then using `map` / `filter` is _less_ readable than the equivalent list comp / gen exp.

Comment: Know when to use each tool.  The use of `map` in @idjaw's answer is much clearer than the equivalent `listcomp`.